# Parsing error, unexpected token Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Following is my code which is giving Parsing error -

Code -

```
const { dataArr, anotherDataArr } = this.props.data
const myArr1 = dataArr.map(item => {'label': item.name,'value': item.code})
const myArr2 = anotherDataArr.map(item => { 'label': item.name, 'value': item.code})

this.setState({
    newArr1: myArr1,
    newArr2: myArr2,
})
```

myArr1, myArr2 should be an array of objects but I am getting parsing error. Let me know what silly mistake I am making here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to implicitly return an object from an arrow function wrap that object in `()`. Wrapping with `()` will make make the object expression. Without `()` `{}` will considered as block.

According to [Returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals):

> The code inside braces `{}` is parsed as a sequence of statements
>   Remember to wrap the object literal in parentheses`()`.

```
const myArr1 = dataArr.map(item => ({'label': item.name,'value': item.code}))
const myArr2 = anotherDataArr.map(item => ({ 'label': item.name, 'value': item.code}))
```